# Collection View Cells Not Showing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I understand there are many questions answering this but my situation is slightly different. Most of the answers tell me to remove this line of code if you are using storyboards:

collectionView?.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

But I can't do that because I am using both storyboards and and non storyboards.

I transition to this collection view controller (non-storyboard view) from a programmatic push view controller (storyboard controller- tab bar controller) like this:

```
func showChatLogController(user: User) {
    let chatLogController = ChatLogController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())
    chatLogController.user = user
    chatLogController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    navigationController?.pushViewController(chatLogController, animated: true)

}
```

My collection view code seems to be write and I have no clue what the problem is. If you need to see the collection view code here it is:

```
let cellId = "cellId"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    collectionView?.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    setUpInputComponents()

    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SignUpViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.height, height: 80)
}
```

For some reason it does not display the cells. I have no clue why. Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I don't know if this is important but to get to the collection view controller I am coming from a tab bar controller.

Comment: Does anyone else have any suggestions to my very strange situation

Comment: Hi Rohan, did you manage to solve this issue? We seem to have the exact same thing happen. I also notice that if I start to scroll where the cells should show, they suddenly appear.

Answer (score 1):

set your collection view's `datasource` and `delegate` to self in your `viewDidload` like,

```
  yourCollectionView.dataSource = self
  yourCollectionView.delegate = self
```

Comment: Does anyone else have any suggestions to my very strange situation

Answer (score 0):

- Is cellForRowAtIndexPath getting called? If you print something in it  does it get logged?
- Is your collection view showing up where you expect? If you set its background color do you see it?
- Print the size you're returning in sizeForItemAtIndexPath. Is it what you expect or is a 0 sneaking in there?

Comment: it is not recognizing my cellForItemAtIndexPath or my sizeForItemAtIndexPath. I have no clue why however it is reading these lines: numberOfItemsInSection and collectionView?.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

Comment: When are you setting the datasource of the collection view? I wonder if the collection view tries to reload data before the cell is registered for reuse. What happens if you call reloadData() after registerClass?

Comment: Does anyone else have any ideas to my very strange situation

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering this issue recently and found that I was instantiating the Collection View controller incorrectly. I was previously instantiating it as:

`let CollectionViewController = CollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())`

When it should be:

`let CollectionViewController = CollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())`